# Scrollview in Cocos2d - android

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

How to Implement Scrolling functionality in cocos2d Surfaceview in android? Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: scrollview available on cocos2d android1, you test scorllview functionailty also there.
https://github.com/ZhouWeikuan/cocos2d/blob/master/cocos2d-android/src/org/cocos2d/extensions/scroll/CCScrollView.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no scroll view available in cocos2d, but check the below details if it can help you.

This example for screen reslution 320 x 480.

1. Make one node with required height. 
   Ex : My screen height is 320 and I made a node of height 640.
2. Add it in the layer and set the position to (0, 320)
3. in method CCTouchMoved() increase the node position as per user touch move value
   EX : CGPoint touchLocation = CCDirector.sharedDirector().convertToGL(CGPoint.ccp(event.getX(), event.getY()));
   node.setPosition(0, 320 + (touchLocation.y - touchlocation.y of touch began))

Hope it will work for you and if any other details required then comment on this

Answer (score 1):

You can direct add android ui scrollview in cocos2d-android 1 like that

```
Activity mActivity=CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity();

View view=(LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(mActivity).inflate(R.layout.level_scroll,null);

mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mActivity.addContentView(view, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

}
```

});

You can make level_scroll.xml as per your requirement.