# How to add ScrollView in Android cocos 2d?

Tags: android, scrollview, cocos2d-android

I am Working on Android cocos 2d and i have 8-10 CCSprites which has to scroll horizontally by click of each sprite their is next CCLayer to load so need to Add ScrollView in CCLayer but i am not getting how to do this i am using  cocos2d-android.jar

i am using this code but not working :-

```
final Activity mActivity=CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity();

        final View view= LayoutInflater.from(mActivity).inflate(R.layout.level_scroll,null);

        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mActivity.addContentView(view, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the layer  to which you have to  add all sprites:

```
public class ItemScrollLayer extends CCLayer{

        ArrayList<ExtraProjectileData> spirtes;
        float scaleX,scaleY;
        public ItemScrollLayer(float scaleX,float scaleY,ArrayList<ExtraProjectileData> sprites,float screensize)
        {
            this.scaleX = scaleX;
            this.scaleY = scaleY;
            this.spirtes = sprites;

            float horizontal_distance = 140*scaleX;


            for(int i = 0;i<sprites.size();i++)
            {
                CCSprite indi_sprite = sprites.get(i).getProjectile();
                indi_sprite.setScale(GameActivity.aspect_Scale(indi_sprite, scaleX, scaleY));

                indi_sprite.setPosition(horizontal_distance+(i*screensize),150*scaleY);
                addChild(indi_sprite);
            }
        }
    }
```

the code to move layer placed in on Touch of my MainLayer:

```
@Override
    public boolean ccTouchesMoved(MotionEvent event)
    {

        System.out.println("Touches Moved Called for UpgradeMenu");
        CGPoint LocationMoved = CCDirector.sharedDirector().convertToGL(CGPoint.make(event.getX(), event.getY()));
        float difference = LocationMoved.x - PrevTouchLocation.x;

        float posX = scroll_layer.getPosition().x + difference;
        scroll_layer.setPosition(CGPoint.make(posX, 0));
        if(posX > 0){
            scroll_layer.setPosition(CGPoint.zero());
        }
        else if(posX < (-size.width)*(sprites.size()-1)){
            System.out.println("Right Limit Exceeded");
            scroll_layer.setPosition((-size.width)*(sprites.size()-1),0);
        }
        if(difference < -5*GameActivity.VEL_FACTOR){
            direction = -1;
        }
        else if(difference > 5*GameActivity.VEL_FACTOR){
            direction = 1;
        }
        PrevTouchLocation = LocationMoved;

        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean ccTouchesEnded(MotionEvent event)
    {
        endLocation = CCDirector.sharedDirector().convertToGL(CGPoint.make(event.getX(), event.getY()));
        if(!moving)
        {
            float total = startLocation.x-endLocation.x;
            if(direction == 1 && !(counter <=0))
            {

                CGPoint move_pos = CGPoint.make(size.width+total, 0);
                CCMoveBy go_left = CCMoveBy.action(0.5f, move_pos);
                CCCallFuncN regulator = CCCallFuncN.action(this, "regulator");
                CCSequence seq = CCSequence.actions(go_left, regulator);
                moving = true;
                scroll_layer.runAction(seq);


                counter--;
                projectilePriceLabel.setString(getCurrentPrice());


            }
            else if(direction == -1 && !(counter >= sprites.size()-1))
            {

                CGPoint move_pos = CGPoint.make(-size.width+total, 0);
                CCMoveBy go_right = CCMoveBy.action(0.5f, move_pos);
                CCCallFuncN regulator = CCCallFuncN.action(this, "regulator");
                CCSequence seq = CCSequence.actions(go_right, regulator);
                moving = true;
                scroll_layer.runAction(seq);

                counter++;
                projectilePriceLabel.setString(getCurrentPrice());



            }
        }
        PrevTouchLocation = CGPoint.zero();
        return true;
    }
```

you can edit as per your requirement

Comment: what is ExtraProjectileData is this class ?please patse this class too.

Comment: can u pleas put these classes on github or somewere else so i can use i am new in cocos Android so not getting

Comment: i am getting Some time NullPointer Exception on Line :- LocationMoved = CCDirector.sharedDirector().convertToGL(
    CGPoint.make(event.getX(), event.getY()));
  difference = LocationMoved.x - PrevTouchLocation.x; not getting how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Check this, its for vertical scrolling. You just need to change little to achieve.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12056450/1614340

Let me know if you can't get any idea from this I will provide code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do by adding all sprites to a parent layer then  move this parent layer by using MoveBy modifier in ccTouchesMoved

Comment: Thanks for reply i had tried but not working can u please paste some code here i need urgently.

Comment: can u pleas put these classes on github or somewere else so i can use i am new in cocos Android so not getting.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for delay. You have to initialize PrevTouchLocation  before you use that as mention below.

```
CGPoint PrevTouchLocation = CGPoint.zero();
```

Comment: Thanks @Rama it's working now.but scroll is not working smoothly i have 5 sprites while scrolling some time clicked or automaticlly clicked in sprite and next layer lodes. is any property that while scrolling can we diable touch on spriete?

Comment: you can check condition direction when it touches the sprites like if((direction> -5 || direction<5) && spritetag).I think it may work

Comment: @ Rama i am getting an problem while scrolling .my scroll is not working when i touch between two sprite or try to scroll on sprite so i have to scroll on top only but client has issue can u please help me